# Spark-xml creating `_VALUE` column which colflicts with other column with _value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, select

I am using Spark to process some datas stored in an XML file.
I successfuly loaded my datas and printed the schema :

```
val df = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag","elementTag")
    .load(myPath+"/myfile.xml")

df.printSchema
```

Which give me a result that look like this :

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- creationDate: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastUpdateDate: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _value: string (nullable = true)
```

From this datas, I want to extract only certain fields , which should be easy with a 'select'. So I am doing the folowing request :

```
df.select("_id","creationDate._value","lastUpdateDate._value")
```

But I get the error :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(_VALUE,StringType,true), StructField(_value,StringType,true);
```

My problem is that spark sql is not case sensitive and my file contains field `_value` and `_VALUE` and I can't change my input file.

Is there a way to solve this probleme with Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) creates `_VALUE` there is no child in a `xml` tag which cause conflict with other.

You can change default value `_VALUE` by adding option while reading `xml` as

```
val df = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag","elementTag")
    .option("valueTag", "anyName")
    .load(myPath+"/myfile.xml")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot !